# Send KeyEvent from EditText

Tags: android

I have tried to send *keyevent* from `EditText`. For this I was using **`InputConnectionWrapper`** which I had taken from method `onCreateInputConnection()`:

```
ZanyInputConnection zic;
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    zic = new ZanyInputConnection(super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs),
            true);
    return zic;
}
```

Inside `ZanyInputConnection` I wrote method which turn on shift:

```
private class ZanyInputConnection extends InputConnectionWrapper {

    public ZanyInputConnection(InputConnection target, boolean mutable) {
        super(target, mutable);
    }

    public void turnOnShift(){
        long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime,
                KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, 0, 0, KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD, 0,
                KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD|KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE));
         sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(eventTime, SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, 0, 0, KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD, 0,
                KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD|KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE));

    }
}
```

It called inside `onSelectionChange()` method:

```
@Override
public void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
    zic.turnOnShoft();
}
```

But when method called nothing happens.

**EDIT:**

If I use KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A later 'a' add, but if I use KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT it doesn't work

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the shift key?

Comment: @user3249477 , I have invisible symbol at start of each paragraph and I need shift to be turned on after that symbol. I cant use  InputType because when I use it I have problem with autocomplete and with deleting text on some devices

Comment: @Dima, Can you clarify your workflow in a bit more detailed way? Otherwise, your code snippets are not being fully helpful (attach more code if necessary to explain the flow). Have you tried to verify whether your onSelectionChanged() is getting called whenever you expect it to?

Comment: I think it will be more usefull to create your own inputtype instead of hacking around with the current ones. For more information see [here][http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html]. But I think this problem can also be sovled using textwatchers or a custom AutoCompleteTextView. Can you explain a bit more how the "invisible" symbol works?

Comment: Can you please tell me .. you want on KeyPressUp or KeyPressDown?? Please post some dummy UI screen-shot

Comment: @user1281750 TextWatcher can't solve the problem, because we want that user to see that shift key is turned on. About invisible symbol: I have invisible symbol at the begin of paragraph(it need for paragraph spans). User doesn't see that symbol, he has to see shift turn on and next symbol which will be inputed by him will be big symbol. When you said own inputtype, did you meen creating own keyboard?

Comment: @Dima How are you sure that `onSelectionChanged` is called ?

Comment: @SimpleGuy I logged it.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just attach the invisible symbol after the user has finished his input? When he accepts or finalizes his input say for example at the press of an accept button. I'm thinking the user does not know about the invisible symbol and you're only using it for formatting after the fact.